# Generate primer with multiprocessing.pool.map, it outputs redundant info

Tags: python

I want to find all primer in [0,M), and write it with multiprocessing.pool.map method, but it output so many None that I don't want. My code like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

M = 100
vi = [0] * M

def do_sieve(p):
    global vi
    if p <= 1:
        vi[p] = -1
        return 
    for i in range(2*p, M, p):
        vi[i] = 1
    if vi[p] == 0:
        return p

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool_size = 4
    pool = Pool(processes = pool_size)
    result = pool.map(do_sieve, range(0, M), 50)
    print result
```

it output like this:

[None, None, 2, 3, None, 5, None, 7, None, None, ......]

I know that's because **do_sieve** will return directly with nothing if p is not primer, so I want **result** just contain all primer. Can anyone help me improve it?

Comment: This will not give the correct result, because (1) the sieve must be filled in order, and (2) each process has its own global variables. (As you have set a chunk size of 50, numbers below 50 will be correctly classified)

Comment: @JanneKarila yes, you're right. I want to remove composite number, but I found do_sieve maintain its own local variables, so I let it return p directly. But my algorithm was wrong, I need think again. Thanks.

Comment: @JanneKarila I'm confused. If you said each process has its own global variables, so 50~99 will be zero at beginning, then 50 will be "primer", but I run my program many times, sometimes the result contains 50 but in the most cases it doesn't contain 50. Does it matter "global vi" in my code?

Comment: @MoreFreeze: `multiprocessing` uses processes so all process state is copied. I think it's a VERY bad idea to use globals with `multiprocessing` (and threads as well). You can look into specialized data structures provided by `multiprocessing` for storing inter-process state.

Answer (score 1):

Just add one more line at the end to filter out the `None`s:

```
result = [i for i in result if i is not None]
```

Comment: Thank your method, it works. But my algorithm was wrong from beginning.

Comment: why `_` and not `i` or `x` or something? `_` usually stands for "unused". Also, `smth is not None` is always favored for comparing against `None`.

Comment: Thanks @Erik. Made those changes.